# Set to inactive instead of deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to set objects to inactive instead of deleting them in rails? Since I need this in almost every of my models it would be nice to have a central spot for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ActsAsParanoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid) gem.